# Problem with opening .tar files

Tags: command-line, tar

I am new to ubuntu (got it last week) and I am having trouble opening .tar files. It comes up with this error:

```
tar (child): tor-browser-linux64-6.0.3_en-US.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have tried this with many files but it is the same error. It is probably something simple but I am not used to OS.
Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

You cant 'open' a .tar file, you need to unzip them like you would at windows, to do this do the following

1. make a folder using `mkdir foldername`
2. move the tar into the folder `mv filename.tar.extension foldername`
3. move inside the folder using `cd foldername`
4. unzip it (I call it untar :P) using `tar xf filename.tar`
5. now you see a lot of files or not as much depending on what is in it

Answer (score 0):

if the tar archive is compressed you have two options:

1. use the integrated option of tar to handle compressed files:

   tar tzf mycompressedtar.tar.z  (for gzip compressed files)

   (or "j" for bzipped files which have a
   higher compression rate)

   tar tjf mybzipcompressedfile.tar.bzip2
2. you can also use a shell pipe.. do decompress first and feed the result directly into tar:

   gzip -dc mygzipcompressed.tgz | tar tf -

   (analog for bzip2 compressed files)

Note: the nice Unix tool "file" helps you identify what compression has been used.